# Android studio ide install error on Mac Yosemite

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, osx-yosemite

When I downloaded `android-studio-ide-141.2135290-mac` and tried installing it on my Mac Yosemite, I faced errors such as:

1. file not found
2. the following SDK components were not installed: platfrom tools,extra-android-m2erepository and extra-google-m2erepository

Answer (score 0):

In OS X run as admin the first time by opening a new Terminal and run the commands:

cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/

sudo ./studio